# Return statement and the calling module in php, based on php.net

Tags: php, return, return-value

> [*RETURN*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)
>
> **"return returns program control to the calling module. Execution resumes at the expression following the called module's invocation."**

What is:

1. "*the calling module*"
2. an invocation of the called module

I was asking some PHP programmers and they are not familiar with these terms. There is no such thing as calling modules in the PHP. Where something like this would be described on the Net (I could not find any info on that)?

Comment: Well, you use return in a function, so the execution resumes from wherever the function was called; so I assume the "calling module" would be the function call. See here: https://3v4l.org/KRFp7

Comment: @JustCarty - The first line sounds like it is not related to functions. How the return works with the functions is described after that.

Comment: "calling module" the first line on the php.net for this. How this could be reworded? What other words or word could I use for the "calling module"?

Comment: Have you read the comments on that post? Do they help you understand the process of return?

Comment: A "module" here is actually the PHP script. The "calling module" then is the script that calls the "called module" which is a different script. If that is not familiar to you this could be the case, b/c this is for the `include` and `require` statements. These are fundamental things in the PHP language, but they are not so commonly used any longer so this might create the disconnection between the wording of the docs and your PHP programming practice (and that of your peers). I take the freedom to remove the PHP version specific tags btw. as this is not PHP version specific.

Comment: Somewhat related: [What actually is a module in software engineering? (closed on SE SE)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/167859/24482)